# Button that executes php function, or custom VBO action

Tags: nodes

I have a function that pushes a node to a sugarCRM database. There have been some problems with the sugarCRM database recently and some of the nodes that were supposed to be pushed were not. I need to be able to build a button that can execute the function manually and push the selected node to the database. Is there a way that I can accomplish this via VBO?

Answer (score 3):

You can create a menu item that does what you want along the lines of

```
function YOURMODULE_menu() {

  $items=array();

  $items['sugarme/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Send this node to sugarCRM',
    'page callback' => 'YOURMODULE_sugarme',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );

  // other menu items here

}

function YOURMODULE_sugarme($nid) {

   if (YOURFUNCTIONTOSENDTHISNIDTOSUGARCRM($nid)) {
     return 'Sent to sugar';
   } else {
     return 'Send to sugar failed';
   }

 }
```

which in the very simple form above (no security, no argument sanity checks, etc) creates a path on your system `www.yourhost.com/sugarme/####` that will call your function with the nid passed to it.